How to self taught Linear Algebra correctly?
I am self teaching linear algebra for AI and computer science with the ambition to be AI researcher. I read Linear Algebra Done Right By Sheldon Axler. I am currently in Chapter 3 Section A.
As so far, I understand all the concepts in the book by reading it by myself. I attempt on doing exercise wherein I could only do 4 to 5 easy questions per sections while for the rest, I always have to look at MathStackExchange, Chatgpt and other sources for solution. Should I go back to more beginner friendly books ? What is the correct ways of self teaching ?

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1079266/221315 Related

ChatGPT often gets mathematics wrong

A good supplement---and I emphasize supplement, not primary resource---is 3Blue1Brown's Essence of Linear Algebra series on YouTube.

First, make sure you're comfortable with basic linear algebra computations such as finding determinants, eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and working with quadratic forms. Once you have a solid grasp of these foundational concepts, you can move on to more abstract topics. Embracing abstraction is essential for understanding broader principles and achieving universality in your studies. The book you're referring to may seem abstract at first, but it's manageable and can significantly enhance your abstract thinking skills. Perseverance will pay off and prepare you for more challenging material in the future.
You can access helpful resources for this book through the following links: here are videos recorded by the author, and here you can find most of the solutions. Use these resources effectively to gain a deep understanding.
Personally, I struggled with the book initially, often having to revisit questions multiple times to grasp them fully. I read the book over three times before it began to feel more approachable, and now it reads easily. This experience has been valuable for tackling more complex texts. Overall, this book is an excellent starting point and will be beneficial for your academic growth.

Thanks for the advice. To clarify, should I keep on reading the same book or step back ? What's your opinion ?

@asdsad Keep on. After you finish this book, you'll find other difficult books are easier to read.
